# can I replace my memory with faster one?

Tags: motherboard, memory

I have a desktop at home. The CPU is i5-6400. Internet search shows me the processor can use DDR4-1866/2133 or DDR3L-1333/1600 @1.35V. I opened the case and found there are two slots, both having DDR3L-1333 4GB modules installed (total 8GB, DIMM module).
I learned I can't insert DDR4 modules becaus the slot is not compatible. Of course I could update to two 8GB DDR3L-1333 modules, but can I upgrade the memory with two 8GB DDR3L-1600 modules? (total 16GB, faster memory). Is there any CPU grade for the memory interface speed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an advantage of running faster memory, although its not much. If you can get the 1600mhz dimms for about the same price or a bit more expensive than the 1333mhz dimms, get the 1600mhz dimms

The performance uplift is small though, so if the 1600mhz dimms are a lot more expensive than the 1333mhz dimms just get the 1333mhz dimms.

Comment: ah, thanks! I see. I was wondering how much the DRAM speed upgrade will have in the overall performance.

Comment: It really depends on what you are doing, it can be 0 to 15 percent (estemate)